# Check whether the rows has the same value based on a unique key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried different ways to check whether the rows has the same value or different value based on multiple key.

Table:

| ParNo | Supp_No | Mat_No | Val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 3340 | 1121 | 3 |
| 1001 | 3340 | 1122 | 3 |
| 1001 | 3340 | 1123 | 3 |
| 1001 | 3341 | 1131 | 4 |
| 1001 | 3341 | 1132 | 2 |
| 1001 | 3341 | 1133 | 3 |
| 1001 | 3341 | 1134 | 1 |
| 1001 | 3342 | NULL | 3 |
| 1001 | 3342 | NULL | 1 |

Problem and condition which needs to be satisfied:
From the above table, based on Supp_No and Mat_No i need to return whether the flag is Yes or No based on the Val.

1. Flag will be Yes for Supp_No 3340 - Because Supp_No is same , Mat_No
   is different and the value for all different materials for same
   suppier is same ie 3.
2. Flag will be No for Supp_No 3341 - Because
   Supp_No is same , Mat_No is different but the value for all
   different materials for same suppier is not the same.
3. Flag will be NA for Supp_No 3342 - Because Supp_No is same , Mat_No is NULL.

Expected:
Flag column is the expected result.

| ParNo | Supp_No | Mat_No | Val | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 3340 | 1121 | 3 | Yes |
| 1001 | 3340 | 1122 | 3 | Yes |
| 1001 | 3340 | 1123 | 3 | Yes |
| 1001 | 3341 | 1131 | 4 | No |
| 1001 | 3341 | 1132 | 2 | No |
| 1001 | 3341 | 1133 | 3 | No |
| 1001 | 3341 | 1134 | 1 | No |
| 1001 | 3342 | NULL | 3 | NA |
| 1001 | 3342 | NULL | 1 | NA |

Solution tried:

1. Tried using group By based on supp_no but it just returns the aggregate and was unable to get the desired result.
2. Tried using parition but was'nt successful.

Thanks in Advance - Any help would be much appreciated as i am a new bie to SQl.

Thank You,

Comment: please tag only the database system that you are using

Comment: Is the above sample table data or the expected result? We need both anyway, a [mcve]. Also show us your current attempt.

Comment: @jarlh - I have added the table with expected results if that helps. Let me know whether you need some more information.

Comment: `I tried different ways ...`.  I don't see a way posted.

Comment: What if there are Mat_No duplicates for a Supp_No - does that mean Flag should be false? (In that case, does it matter if Val is same/different?) Add that case to your example.

Comment: @jarlh The Mat_No for a Supp_No would always be unique. There wont be any duplicate Mat_No.(Functionally - As there will be unique Material Nos for each materials for a supplier)

Comment: What about parno? Does that value matter?

Comment: Also, which dbms are you using? (Different products have different possibilities here.)

Comment: @jarlh ParNo will always have the same value as the Brand Name is same, I am using SQl Server, Relational DBMS.

Comment: Too bad you aren't using Oracle... https://dbfiddle.uk/kaMazjZI

Comment: @jarlh : getting this error "Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause." while using your query and if i remove distinct i get the flag result as NO for all the records.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server doesn't support what Oracle does. But see my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but I have some reservations about it.

```
SELECT
        ParNo
       ,Supp_No
       ,Mat_No
       ,Val
       ,(
          CASE WHEN AVG_TABLE.VAL_AVG IS NULL
               THEN 'NA'
               WHEN AVG_TABLE.VAL_AVG = THE_TABLE.VAL
               THEN 'Yes'
               ELSE 'No'
          END
        ) AS Flag
  FROM
        THE_TABLE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                            SELECT ParNo
                                  ,Supp_No
                                  ,Mat_No
                                 ,AVG(VAL) AS VAL_AVG
                             FROM THE_TABLE
                         GROUP BY ParNo
                                 ,Supp_No
                                 ,Mat_No  
                       ) AS AVG_TABLE
                   ON THE_TABLE.ParNo = AVG_TABLE.ParNo
                  AND THE_TABLE.Supp_No = AVG_TABLE.Supp_No
                  AND THE_TABLE.Mat_No = AVG_TABLE.Mat_No
```

I'm not exactly sure it's the most efficient way to go about it. If any one Mat_No is NULL, it may be excluded depending on your system. You'll only get NA if they are all null for a particular ParNo and Supp_No. Finally, binary division issues could cause a false negative.

There's probably a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case expression combined with window functions to set flag to Yes/No:

```
select t.*,
       case when count(*) over (partition by supp_no) =
                   count(mat_no) over (partition by supp_no) 
             and max(val) over (partition by supp_no) = 
                   min(val) over (partition by supp_no)
              then 'Yes'
            when count(mat_no) over (partition by supp_no) > 0
              then 'No'
            else 'NA'
       end as flg
from t
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/4kbaHWsO

Comment: How will i differentiate between NA

Comment: Oops. missed that part. Now edited, try again!

Comment: Can we also please add this condition to the fiddler ,1. Case 'No' - Need to have more that one (mat_no)    2. Case 'Yes' - Can have one mat_no and if more that one mat_no, same lead time.  I tried adding count(mat_no) > 1 in Case 'No' and count(mat_no) = 1 or  count(mat_no) > 1, Let me know whether my solution is right or should i do some thing else - Thanks in advance

Comment: I am referring to mat_no 's for the same supp_no , - I assume that this condition is covered in whatever query you had given but tried to add that condition on top of it.